# Trying to return 1 row for search on multiple values in child table in a view

Tags: sql-server-2005

Table 1 uses joining Table2 for a many to many relationship with Table 3.

### Table1

ID

### Table2

Table1ID
Table3ID

### Table3

ID
SomeData

I want a query that will return only 1 instance of a row from Table1 for a search for multiple Table2.ID's

Table1:
ID

1

2

3

4

Table 2

1 1

1 2

2 2

2 3

Table3

1 "foo"

2 "bar"

3 "whizz"

4 "bang"

Now I can do a join with a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
 WHERE ID in (

SELECT DISTINCT(T1.ID)
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
ON T1.ID = T2.Table1ID
WHERE T2.Table3ID in (1,2)
```

)

where 1 and 2 are the values I'm searching for.

Now I want to wrap this up in a view so I can query something like:

```
Select ID, {other stuff from T1} from vwGetData
```

where Value in (1,2)

Is this possible? hope I made it clear enough

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need some values from Table1 your query should look like this:

```
select T1.*
from Table1 as T1
where T1.ID in (select T2.Table1ID      
                from Table2 as T2
                where T2.Table2ID in (1, 2))
```

There is no way to create a view of that and allow you to add in the filter on (1, 2) as a where clause to the query of the view.

Your sample query against the view only retrieves the ID column so to get that information you don't need to involve `Table1` in the query.

```
select distinct T2.Table1ID as ID
from Table2 as T2
where T2.Table2ID in (1, 2)
```

You could create a view of that (without the `distinct` part) but that would not make much sense at all would it?

```
create view v_Table2
as
select Table1ID, Table2ID
from Table2
```

Used like this:

```
select distinct T2.Table1ID as ID
from v_Table2 as T2
where T2.Table2ID in (1, 2)
```

The view does not really add any value.

Comment: the real query needs a ton of more stuff from table 1, I just cut it down for the example. I've updated the question.